# Classify strings via class using sklearn

Tags: python, string, scipy, scikit-learn, gaussian

I'm having issues with presenting my data in a form which sklearn will accept
My raw data is a few hundred strings, and these are classified into one of 5 classes, I've a list of the strings i'd like to classify, and a parallel list of their respective classes. I'm using `GaussianNB()`

Example Data:

```
For such a large, successful business, I really feel like they need to be 
either choosier in their employee selection or teach their employees to 
better serve their customers.|||Class:4
```

Which represents a given "feature" and a classification

Naturally, the strings themselves have to be converted to vectors prior to their use in the classifier, I've attempted to use `DictVector` to perform this task

```
dictionaryTraining = convertListToSentence(data)
vec = DictVectorizer()
print(dictionaryTraining)
vec.fit_transform(dictionaryTraining)
```

However in order todo it, i have to attach the actual classification of the data into the dictionary, otherwise i get the error `'str' object has no attribute 'items'` I understand this is because `.fit_transform` requires features and indices, but i don't fully understand the purpose of the indice

```
fit_transform(X[, y])   Learn a list of feature name -> indices mappings and transform X.
```

My question is, how can i take a list of strings, and a list of numbers representing their classifications, and provide these to a `gaussianNB()` classifier such that i can present it with a similar string in the future and it will estimate the strings class?

Comment: Can you share the format of your data in the `dictionaryTraining ` variable?

Comment: The format does not work unless i set the format to be strings -> classification, but obviously that is not what the classifier requires

Answer (score 1):

Since your input data are in the format of raw text and not in the format of a dictionary where like {"word":number_of_occurrences, } I believe you should go with a [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) which will split your input text on white space and transform it on the input vectors you need.

A simple example of such a transformation would be:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = ['This is the first document.', 'This is the second second document.', 
          'And the third one.', 'Is this the first document?',]
x = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(corpus)
print x.todense() #x holds your features. Here I am only vizualizing it
```

Comment: do you have an example about how i would go about taking a list of strings and a parallel list of the strings classifications, turn these into a countvectorisor and input to the classifier?